# Adding and removing classes to sections from links

Tags: javascript

I am not good at javascript and have been chasing myself in circles on this for two days, and nothing works!   I have the below code.  When I click the items (1,2,3) at the top, I need them to link down to the related places below. That works, not a problem.

However, I also need to remove the "active" class from any section that is currently active (the page loads with id item1_1 active) and apply the active class to the item1_1, item1_2, or item1_3 sections.

Any assistance or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
        <div class="body">
        <div role="main" class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <a href="#item1">Item 1</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <a href="#item2">Item 2</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <a href="#item3">Item 3</a>
                            </div>
                </div>
                    <div id="item1"></div>
                <div class="toggle toggle-primary" data-plugin-toggle data-plugin-options="{ 'isAccordion': true }">
                    <div id="item2"></div>
                    <section id="item1_1" class="toggle active">
                        <a class="toggle-title"><strong>Item 1</strong></a>
                        <div class="toggle-content">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lacus elit, venenatis vel ultricies eu, dapibus at ligula. Integer vulputate scelerisque nunc, id eleifend tellus tincidunt vitae.</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <div id="item3"></div>
                    <section id="item2_1" class="toggle">
                        <a class="toggle-title"><strong>Item 2</strong></a>
                        <div class="toggle-content">
                            <p>Proin non quam vel mauris tempor accumsan vitae ultrices risus. Fusce euismod, orci ut scelerisque porta, justo nibh mollis leo, nec aliquam tellus diam ut orci. </p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section id="item3_1" class="toggle">
                        <a class="toggle-title"><strong>Item 3</strong></a>
                        <div class="toggle-content">
                            <p>Nulla maximus mauris quis pharetra volutpat. Donec luctus leo ligula, ut efficitur erat vehicula non. Quisque justo dui, aliquam at lobortis eu, accumsan sit amet massa. Nulla nec odio vitae mauris venenatis interdum sit amet at ex. Aenean dapibus convallis dolor, sit amet luctus purus ultrices ac.  </p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: whenever a `.toggle` is clicked , perform `element.classlist.remove('active')` on all `.toggle` elements and perform `this.classlist.add('active')` on the clicked element [read more](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Answer (score 0):

the below might help you:

1. Give the `<div>` containing the item1, 2, 3 an `id="links-container"`
2. giving the item1, 2, 3 `id="item1-btn"`, `id="item2-btn"`, `id="item3-btn"`
3. Add a click event which run a function to remove the class "active" from any element that has it, and then add this class to the appropriate element

```js
//using js vanilla

//1- giving the div containing the item1, 2, 3 an id="links-container"
//2- giving the item1, 2, 3 id="item1-btn", id="item2-btn", id="item3-btn"
//3- adding click event to the anchor tags    
let linksContainer = document.getElementById("links-container").querySelectorAll("a");
for (let i = 0; i < linksContainer.length; i++) {
  linksContainer[i].addEventListener("click", moveActiveClass);
}

function moveActiveClass() {
  //first of all lets remove the class "active" from the element which has it
  document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
  //now lets add the class "active" to the appropriate section tag
  let clickedButtonID = event.target.getAttribute("id");
  switch (clickedButtonID) {
    case "item1-btn":
      console.log("item1 was clicked");
      //Add the class "active" to section1          
      document.getElementById("item1_1").classList.add("active");
      break;
    case "item2-btn":
      console.log("item2 was clicked");
      //Add the class "active" to section2
      document.getElementById("item2_1").classList.add("active");
      break;
    case "item3-btn":
      console.log("item3 was clicked");
      //Add the class "active" to section3
      document.getElementById("item3_1").classList.add("active");
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div role="main" class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="links-container">
        <div class="col">
          <a id="item1-btn" href="#item1">Item 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a id="item2-btn" href="#item2">Item 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a id="item3-btn" href="#item3">Item 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item1"></div>
      <div class="toggle toggle-primary" data-plugin-toggle data-plugin-options="{ 'isAccordion': true }">
        <div id="item2"></div>
        <section id="item1_1" class="toggle active">
          <a class="toggle-title"><strong>Item 1</strong></a>
          <div class="toggle-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lacus elit, venenatis vel ultricies eu, dapibus at ligula. Integer vulputate scelerisque nunc, id eleifend tellus tincidunt vitae.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <div id="item3"></div>
        <section id="item2_1" class="toggle">
          <a class="toggle-title"><strong>Item 2</strong></a>
          <div class="toggle-content">
            <p>Proin non quam vel mauris tempor accumsan vitae ultrices risus. Fusce euismod, orci ut scelerisque porta, justo nibh mollis leo, nec aliquam tellus diam ut orci. </p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="item3_1" class="toggle">
          <a class="toggle-title"><strong>Item 3</strong></a>
          <div class="toggle-content">
            <p>Nulla maximus mauris quis pharetra volutpat. Donec luctus leo ligula, ut efficitur erat vehicula non. Quisque justo dui, aliquam at lobortis eu, accumsan sit amet massa. Nulla nec odio vitae mauris venenatis interdum sit amet at ex. Aenean
              dapibus convallis dolor, sit amet luctus purus ultrices ac. </p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```